# Why Exception is not instance of Throwable?

Tags: php, oop, php-5.6

I think in all programming languages `Exception` class is instance of `Throwable` interface.

Take a look at following code which shows `Exception` is not instance of `Throwable` in php.

```
try {

    throw new InvalidArgumentException("error message");

} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {

    if ($e instanceof Exception) {
        echo '$e is exception';             // this line gets executed
    }

    if ($e instanceof Throwable) {
        echo '$e is throwable';             // but this one never
    }

}
```

It makes problem with chaining exceptions where `Exception` class constructor accepts `Throwable` in it's last argument.

php version: `5.6.23`

Any solution?

Comment: Yes it does - https://eval.in/785678

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Throwable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) is the base interface for any object that can be thrown via a `throw` statement in **PHP 7**, including `Error` and `Exception`. And your code produces: `$e is exception $e is throwable` if you have **PHP version >= 7**

But you have PHP version **5.6.23**, so `Throwable` interface is **not available for this version**.

Comment: Had this problem while thinking I am on php7, but actually php7 was installed, but the 5.6 configured in the config file... luckly your post made me check that twice before searching for more.